# Xcode Core Data template trying to load managed object model with a wrong extension

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I have created an app and enabled Core Data in it, and it was trying to load the managed object model with this code :

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MyAppName", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()
```

But at runtime, I had a fatal error, because I was force unwrapping an optional that was nil : **there was no `MyAppName.momd` in my app bundle.**
Instead, there was as `MyAppName.mom`, I changed the extension of the `modelURL` and now it works fine.

But why was there this issue ? I am a newbie to Core Data, but the last times I tried it I had never faced this issue ! Why has the file extension changed for my project ?

How can I be sure that when loading a managed object model, it will be the one with the good extension ? If you want to ship an app, it's not a really reassuring feeling not to know what file extension you must expect !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- momd = a directory of versioned moms.
  [image]
  versioned but no versions: 
  [image]
- mom = a single mom
  (called model and not modeld) :)

So if you have your CoreData Model set as 'versioned' you have a momd. What is versioning in this case? 
every time the database changes you have a mom matching that exact 'snapshot' and to be able to upgrade databases, core data needs all moms.. so you got a momd (a folder) full of moms

that should help you pick the right extension ;)

Comment: Where can I see wether my Core Data model is versioned or not ?

Comment: Nope, it isn't expandable. But what I can't understand is why there is this bug here and not for other projects ? I just created an other one that doesn't seem to be versioned, and it loads successfully the .momd !

Comment: called model => versioned, called model => unversioned | sorry for confusing you with the expandability comment

Comment: Oh, yeah, actually new projects have a .xcdatamodeld extension while mine has only .xdatamodel still can't understand why it didn't behaved like any other projet, but thank you, now I understand the difference between .mom and .momd !